# Как выбирать клетки в шахматном порядке?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть табличка 8x8. По дефолту каждая ее клетка имеет белый цвет, я хочу окрасить их в шахматном порядке. Немного поизучав NodeList я написал следующий код. Как мне сделать чтобы клетки красились в шахматном порядке? Есть идея чтобы менять алгоритм окраски каждую строку, но как это сделать не представляю.

```js
let chess_plate_cells = document.querySelectorAll('table>tbody>tr>td');
let chess_plate_rows = document.querySelectorAll('table>tbody>tr');

chess_plate_cells.forEach(function(cell, index, list){
    if(index%2 == 0){
        cell.classList.toggle('black-cell')
    }
        else {cell.classList.toggle('white-cell')}
})
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
}

td {
    background-color: white;
    width: 5vw;
    height: 5vw;
}

table {
    empty-cells: show;
}

.black-cell {
    background-color: black;
}

.white-cell {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chess Plate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <table class="chess-plate">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Каждая клетка определяется колонкой и строкой. Сейчас для окраски используется только номер колонки (если четная - то клетка черная), а нужно учитывать оба параметра.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно два цикла: один для рядов, другой для клеток в текущем ряду. И проверять нужно четность и того, и другого.

Ниже пример:

```js
let chess_plate_rows = document.querySelectorAll('table>tbody>tr');

chess_plate_rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    let chess_plate_row_cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');
    chess_plate_row_cells.forEach(function(cell, i){
      if((index + i) % 2 == 0) { // было if (index %2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0 || index %2 == 1 && i % 2 == 1)
        cell.classList.toggle('black-cell')
      }
        else {cell.classList.toggle('white-cell')}
        
     })
})
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
}

td {
    background-color: white;
    width: 5vw;
    height: 5vw;
}

table {
    empty-cells: show;
}

.black-cell {
    background-color: black;
}

.white-cell {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chess Plate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <table class="chess-plate">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**UPD**: Добавлена правка от @Эникейщик

Comment: О как, такой же ответ) Удалю свой тогда)

Comment: монстра ``if (index %2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0 || index %2 == 1 && i % 2 == 1)`` можно заменить на ``if ((index + i) % 2 == 0)``. Достаточно проверить четность суммы номеров ряда и строки.

Comment: @Эникейщик, точно, спасибо, поправил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Могу еще предложить вариант на чистом CSS с использованием [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
.chess-plate tr td {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.chess-plate tr td,
.chess-plate tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2n) {
  background: black;
}
.chess-plate tr:nth-child(2n) td,
.chess-plate tr td:nth-child(2n) {
  background: white;
}

/*

ИЛИ

.chess-plate tr td {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: white;
}
.chess-plate tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2n),
.chess-plate tr:not(:nth-child(2n)) td:not(:nth-child(2n)) {
  background: black;
}

*/
```

```html
<table class="chess-plate">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

А надо было изучать css...

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: darkslateblue;
}

td {
  background: white;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) > td:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(even) > td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
</table>
```